# How can I stay logged into two different Discord accounts simultaneously without requiring two unique phone numbers?

Tags: multi-factor-auth, verification, cookies, discord, phone-number

[image: Discord Verification Required screenshot]

I have two separate Discord accounts, and I want to be logged into both of them at the same time. We'll call them "Account A", and "Account B".

I have tried logging into Account A in Firefox, and into Account B in Internet Explorer. I have also tried using the Desktop App for one or the other.

When I try to log into Account A, it gives me the message: "Verification Required", and my only option is "Verify by Phone".

I am able to successfully log into Account A by using my phone number.

When I try to log into Account B, it gives me the message: "Verification Required", and my only option is "Verify by Phone".

I am able to successfully log into Account B by using the same phone number I used for Account A.

However, when I check my DMs in Account A, they will say that they've failed to load, and when I refresh the page, it appears that I have been logged out.

When I try to log back into Account A, it gives me the message: "Verification Required", and my only option is "Verify by Phone".

It will repeat like this ad infinitum if I try to log into Account B. Discord is only letting me keep one account active, rather than allow me to have both active at the same time.

I am guessing that I would require two unique phone numbers in order to keep both accounts active simultaneously. Therefore, I am looking for a way to bypass this restriction.

Note: Discord Support [LINK](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/6181726888215-Verification-Required-FAQ#h_01G3CTDAACPA8E9BRFWCQNSBY4) explains that verification may be required for the following reasons:

- joined multiple servers in a short period of time
- direct messaged multiple users who are not your friends
- sent messages or posted content to communities faster than a human can manage
- used third-party clients or modifications to Discord

I have done the first two things, joining four or so servers quickly. I have messaged around 5 or so people who were not my friends, which is an expected behaviour of the servers I was in (people post "ads" and other users respond to them with a DM / direct message).

Note: Just to be even more clear, I am not talking about two-factor authentication. I do not have two-factor authentication enabled on either account.

Other details:

Being logged into two different accounts, one on my computer and one on my phone, would not solve my problem in spirit since the phone is not convenient for me to use.

HOWEVER, I did try to log into either Account A or B on Discord on my phone through Firefox while using mobile Data instead of wifi. I got an email asking me to confirm the login through a new location, but otherwise the issue persists: When I log into one account, I am logged out of the other one. So Account A was logged out of Firefox on my desktop computer when I logged into Account B on my mobile phone.

Also, it seems that I am not able to successfully log into either Account A or Account B using the Discord mobile app. I am simply brought to a second "Verification Required" message identical to the first, but the option "Verify by Phone" is missing. However, I am able to press the back arrow at the top left to go back to the beginning to try again.

Actually, it seems that I CAN log into the Discord app on my phone, given that I'm already logged into the same account on my computer? For example, I was able to log into Account A in the Discord app on my phone, when I was logged into Account A on my computer.

I have tried the service "TextNow" to get a second phone number, but Discord gave me the error "Please use a valid mobile phone number, not a VoIP or landline number".

To clarify how I was able to associate the same phone number with two different accounts: Well, I am not doing anything special. When I try to log into Account A, Discord asks me for a phone number, and I input my phone number. Then I get a code in a text message and use it to continue to log in. When I try to log into Account B, I use the same phone number and use the code that I was sent by text. Actually, what I think may be happening is that when I use the same number for Account B, it is actually **disassociating** that number with Account A.

(I desire to have two accounts active at once because one is my main account that I use to talk with close friends, and the other is an alt that I use for stuff I don't want my friends to see.)

#### How can I stay logged into two different Discord accounts simultaneously without requiring two unique phone numbers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it can be distilled down to the following:  **1.** How can I bypass Discord's restriction?  or **2.** Where can I get a cheap phone number?"  Neither of these is a practical question about using Discord's Web Application.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying trickery with two browsers, use the built in account switcher.

At the bottom left, click on your name/picture, "Switch Accounts", and "Manage Accounts". From there you can "Add an account". Once you've added another account, this same menu will allow you to switch between the two or log out.

I followed these steps myself and it worked. (Only my main account has my phone number attached.)

Note that you can always add two factor authentication to alt accounts using an authenticator app. Don't get hacked!

For an image guide see the article [What Is an Alt Account on Discord?](https://www.itgeared.com/what-is-an-alt-account-on-discord/). While it was written about the desktop app, the web app looks (and works!) exactly the same.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147323/discussion-on-answer-by-laurel-how-can-i-stay-logged-into-2-different-discord-ac); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.